# How to find value of a key on tail -f

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sed, grep

My log files are in key-value format. I want to find value of a particular key on tail -f .. 
Suppose one of the line in log is:

```
ts=2016-12-23-18-31-34-849 | deviceType=LENOVO Lenovo A6000 | elapsed=11 | firstHomePage=null | installId=37797b61-0bb1-4c1a-844c-5904c7e83de8 | ip=157.48.104.146 
ts=2016-12-23-18-31-34-849 | deviceType=LENOVO Lenovo A6000 | elapsed=15 | firstHomePage=null | installId=37797b61-0bb1-4c1a-844c-5904c7e83de8 | ip=157.48.104.146
```

I am not sure how do I pipe output of my tail -f so that output should be following

```
11
15
```

Comment: Is it a continuously growing file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GNU grep` with the `--line-buffered` command to buffer `stdout` as it arrives in case of continuously growing file. The `-o` flag for matching only the pattern and `-P` to enable `perl` style `regEx` captures.

```
tail -f file | grep --line-buffered -oP "elapsed=\K(\d+)"
11
15
```

From the `man grep` page,

```
--line-buffered
         Use line buffering on output.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `grep`:

```
tail log_file | grep -o '\<elapsed=[^[:space:]]*' | cut -d= -f2
```

Comment: @Deepak I have tested my command with your sample. But you may have a different Unix or grep than mine. I have updated my answer to replace '\S' with an alternate syntax.

Comment: Thanks .. results were coming after some time and in chunks.. using --line-buffered along with your this command works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[=|]' '{print $6}' file
11 
15
```

Comment: I actually think this is the best solution because it is the most concise +1